# Getting 'this.props.user' is undefined when trying to connect React component with Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to create a React component using JSON Placeholder REST API using redux as state management API. I am able to see action getting dispatched in redux logger, but somehow when i am trying to access the changed states through component's property i am getting 'this.props.user' is undefined in browser console window. Please find my code below :

Reducer:

```
import {FETCH_DATA} from  '../Actions/actionTypes';

const initialState={
    userlist:[]
}

function jphReducer(state=initialState,action){
      switch(action.type){

          case FETCH_DATA:
              
              state={
                  ...state,
                  userlist:action.payload
              }
            
            break;
          default :
             state;
      }
      return state;
}

export default jphReducer;
```

Action:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {FETCH_DATA} from  '../Actions/actionTypes';

 export  const  getjphData = () => async dispatch => {
      await  axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then(
          response => {
               dispatch({
                  type:FETCH_DATA,
                  payload:response.data
                  
              });
          },
          reason => {
              dispatch({
                  type:FETCH_DATA,
                  payload:reason
              });
          }
      );
 }
```

MainComponent:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {getjphData} from  '../app/Actions/jphAction';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import jphReducer from '../app/Reducers/jphReducer';
import propTypes from "prop-types";
import { FETCH_DATA } from './Actions/actionTypes';

 class MainComponent extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        
        super(props);
        
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        
        this.props.getData(); 
        
           
    }
     render(){
        
         return(
            
               <div>
                
                 <table>
                     <thead>
                     <th>
                         <td>ID</td>
                         <td>name</td>
                         <td>username</td>
                         <td>Email</td>
                     </th>
                     </thead>
                     <tbody>
                    {
                        
                        this.props.users.map((user) =>
                          <tr>
                              <td>{user.id}</td>
                              <td>{user.name}</td>
                              <td>{user.username}</td>
                              <td>{user.email}</td>
                          </tr>
                        )
                    }
                     </tbody>
                 </table>
                
             </div>
             
         );
           
         
     }
 }

 const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    getData :  dispatch(getjphData())
    
});

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    
    
        users: state.userlist
    
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(MainComponent);
```

Root Component :

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {jphStore} from  './jphStore';
import MainComponent from './MainComponent';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default class RootComponent extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <Provider store={jphStore}> 
                <MainComponent/>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `users.map` tries to run right away even before the request to get the users is done so to make sure that `props.users` is defined before trying to map over it add a condition before it like this `this.props.users && this.props.users.map...`

Your `tbody`shoud look like this

```
      <tbody>
          {
              this.props.users && this.props.users.map((user) =>
                  <tr>
                      <td>{user.id}</td>
                      <td>{user.name}</td>
                      <td>{user.username}</td>
                      <td>{user.email}</td>
                  </tr>
              )
          }
       </tbody>
```

Comment: thanks! that was the only thing missing...it worked